# Bash scripting: using forinloop with an array

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make an script that will print out all the literals in the array using an forin loop... Only my first literal gets printed... Some help?

```
#!/bin/bash
somearray=( p 5 6 j 050yh0k 0 hkofohkf 50 )
for k in somearray
do
echo ${somearray[k]}
done
```

Comment: Read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 -- it explains using arrays for you.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get all of the elements of an array, you need to use the construct `${var[@]}`.  So, to iterate a `for` loop through all members of an array:

```
for element in "${somearray[@]}"; do
    echo "$element"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop over the indices of the array as you initially tried to do:

```
for k in "${!somearray[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "${somearray[k]}"
done
```